# When you delete a really really bad answer, should you still be penalized?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting

If you get tons of down votes for an answer, should you be allowed to delete it and reclaim your points?

I thought the answer could be removed, but you still lose the points. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this will reward you with a `[Peer Pressure]` badge if the votes total -3 or less, but you will not get your reputation back. There has to be something you put on the line when you want to post answers of questionable merit.

As for the recalculation, I don't believe you get your reputation back for downvotes on deleted posts.

Remember, you can always make your answer "Community Wiki" and you will not gain or lose any reputation even if you are downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Also remember that this is not what CW was made for.

Comment: Actually, that seems perfectly valid, as since others can edit the post, they can formulate it into something worthwhile, even if you originally didn't.  So downvoting a community wiki entry is probably just lazy.

Answer (score 4):

Reputation is recalculated from time to time, so you still show the rep loss until that happens.

After that you get it back

Comment: Are you sure you get it back? I seem to remember hearing that *gained* rep from a deleted answer disappears, but *lost* rep from a deleted answer stays.

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/ you do not regain rep lost from a deleted answer, but yes, you do in fact lose rep gained. All upon recalc, of course.