# Should I change this old answer with dubious advice?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange-history

Should I change [this old meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27444/155556) since it has some risky info (RE: CW posts)?

[image: Nooooooo!]

Comment: Sorry - I should have looked to see who was asking before answering.  I'm sure you know what the recalc rules are.  I'll let everyone else opine about the CW stuff

Comment: What risk are you talking about? This answer has been there for a while and we don't see rampant use of _bad_ CW answers (Pekka not withstanding ;)).

Comment: *slapping @Oded with glove* **Slander!** I demand [satisfaction!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel)

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. - Dawn at Games? Or would tex suit you better?

Comment: @Oded [here](http://firearms.stackexchange.com/), at dawn.

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. - perfect!

Comment: @Oded yeah. That way, we can even get immediate free assistance if rusty barrels or jammed triggers prevent us from seeing this through!

Comment: Pretty sure any Firearms SE user worth his salt would know to be as far away from you two as possible, actually, @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. (cont'd)

Comment: and @Oded. Also, wouldn't Adam Davis have been a much more appropriate target? How quickly we forget....

Comment: @Pop you mean they have a "what to do if the OP wants to shoot themselves in the foot" policy over on Firearms.SE just as we do on SO, only much more literally? Well, that's probably a good thing.

Comment: @PopularDemand, for a moment there I thought you were going to propose Adam Davis as a weapon :)

Answer (score 4):

Everything but the bit about the badge is either wrong or shady. Namely, you will get the reputation back if you perform a recalculation. Secondly, you shouldn't use Community Wiki to shield yourself from downvotes if your answer is wrong.

You should either edit the answer or (if you want the rep) add your *own* answer that correct's the first's bad information. (If it were me, I'd provide a new answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that answer should be handled as any other answer given on an SE site.

You should not edit it, if you are going to change its meaning. If you think the answer is promoting something that should not be done, then you can down-vote it.
As the answer doesn't seem updated (or the user wrote something wrong), you could also add an answer for what happens now. The OP intact reports that a recalc doesn't give you back the reputation you lost because down-votes you got for a post that is then deleted; as far as I know, the the recalc triggered at sitename.com/reputation gives you back the reputation you lost because down-votes on a deleted post (and removes the reputation gain because up-votes on a deleted post).