# How to solve the problem of lack of deletion-protection for negative answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, deleted-answers

Today was the second (or third) time this happened to me on SO.

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11903889/1000282) and some high reputation fellow has answered it with a *possible* solution. Specifically, the User suggested me to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en), I've downvoted it because it was not verified by the User if it worked, he then said about an <kbd>option</kbd> to <kbd>alt</kbd> map that I discovered didn't exist and made no sense. I've checked all by myself installing the tool and trying his key mappings with it to get on this conclusion.

The information that a *possible* solution doesn't work **is valuable** (e.g. anyone trying to solve the same problem could eliminate the work of verifying it before hand).

I think, because of his single downvote or little shame, he just deleted the answer (and all the comments along), [just like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/179067).

To me, all this is not fair. I think this may be related to the [pity problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93356/179067), since the fellows are promptly deleting his downvoted answers, leaving only the upvoted-protected.

By downvoting I got -1 rep, a little after his deletion, it came back, but I've not minded by getting -1.

Is there a solution to this?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I thought there was answer protection, but as everyone is saying, there is not.

Comment: Unless the answer is abysmal, consider not down-voting posts to your own question.  That's probably why the user deleted his answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis Well, I think not, I may have not downvoted it, after I've checked by myself and he could see how he was wrong, he would delete it anyway even with 0 votes. So, what I said would apply to a answer with 0 votes. The problem is that IT IS VALUABLE by elimination

Comment: I've been on Stack Overflow for a decent amount of time -- I can assure you that downvoted answers are much, much more likely to be deleted than answers with 0 votes, as Dennis said.

Comment: @AdamRackis This was the time I'm manifesting myself, but I don't remember downvoting before, in the other ocasions as I said, and they got deleted.

Comment: So your expectation is that every single answer has to be personally tested and verified to work before posting it? I've answered literally hundreds of questions on SO where I don't have any access to something to test it (like how to fix a query that isn't working right, where the solution is clear to me but I don't have access to the user's multi-gigabyte database to test). If "suggested solutions" aren't allowed, there would be a whole lot more unanswered questions here. Because a suggestion doesn't work for you doesn't mean you should automatically punish the effort to help by downvoting.

Comment: @KenWhite What effort? anyway, I'm not discussing the -1, the problem is the deletion. I was misinformed, I though there was answer protection bias by the rules of SO, and there isn't. So that's it... I expect to see a lot of answer with value in some way or another just popping out because of a -1 or little shame.

Comment: You downvoted an answer and then were upset when it was deleted? :confused:

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's not that I was upset. It's about playing a fair game. This question is more about a bias I thought there was of upvoted-answers against (down/non)voted. Or you get protection for all, or for no one. I was upset by that happening through that bias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I will answer my own question, as BoltClock's a Unicorn pointed, there is no answer protection against self-deletion.

I was misinformed, I thought there was answer protection bias by the rules of SO, and there isn't. So that's it... I expect to see a lot of answers with value in some way or another (who said that negative value is aways not *valuable*?) just popping out because of a -1 or little shame.

At last it's not in the SO DNA.

Answer (score 12):

You're contradicting yourself.

The tooltip for downvoting reads **This answer is not useful**. If you honestly think so, by all means, downvote the answer.

However, if you *do* think that the answer has some value (and answers containing *possible* solutions frequently have), just don't downvote the answer. The vast majority of these answers won't get deleted.

Put yourself in the answerer's shoes: You answered a question in good faith, although you couldn't verify that the proposed solution would actually work. As a reward, you lost 2 reputation points. What incentive do you have *not* to delete your answer? None.

Comment: The User could verify, I'm sure, he just had not, just leaving as an short unverified suggestion which I've checked by myself, and full of misinformation. Now, even if I had not downvoted it, do 0 votes answers get protection? If not, they are at the same boat as the downvoted ones as I said to Adam Rackis.

Comment: Any user can delete any of their own answers of any score, any time they choose. The only "protection" that answers with at least 0 score have is against being deleted by votes from *other people* (with sufficient rep privileges).

Comment: There isn't *any* protection for answers. It doesn't matter if your answer has a score of -1, 0 or 42, you can delete it (as long as it's not locked or accepted). I don't have the necessary reputation to see deleted answers on SO, but if the answer was really just a *short unverified suggestion [...] full of misinformation*, deletion sounds like a good call to me.

Comment: @Dennis It is not a good call, there's a tool, that may work, someone suggested it as a solution, I verified as he said, and it was a lie, It doesn't work it that case, but the tool indeed looks, only looks, like it may work. It was not a good answer, the only value of it was I verifing that it was not, so anyone could know that it was not.

Comment: Then edit it into your question: I've tried XYZ, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Dennis yeaahhh.... I could do that. But I could die of infarct while editing and not submitting. But the question would still be there and the downvoted answer not.

Comment: A heart attack at 27 and you worry about a deleted answer full of misinformation? I think you have your priorities wrong...

Comment: @Dennis Who doens't :-)

Comment: @Chico - The final comment on the deleted answer is *There's a way to make this work; I just don't have time to follow up so I'm deleting this answer*. If there are other upvoted answers to a question, you can sometimes just as well delete your own partial answer.

Comment: @BoPersson oh my, I think I'll need to draw... 1 - Still, there's no proper answer; 2 - someone answered as **Hey I'm sure X works**; 3 - I've checked, it **does not**, but it looked, and still looks as it may work, but will not; 4 - All this was embedded in the answer + comments. The information that it doesn't works, embedded in the discussion, not in the answer, **is** valuable. It *is* valuable to someone researching for a solution, which is still not fully answered at SO, but from where he could eliminate what is already known not working.

Comment: @BoPersson *even if* it really looks like as a candidate solution to everyone.